# iText7 C# - Merging same pdf document multiple times reduces file size

Tags: c#, itext7

I have a .NET 6.0 Windows Forms Application with iText7 added from NuGet package manager.

In the UI I have:

- A Open File Dialogue to allow user to select a single .pdf file
- A text box to allow to enter a number. Content of the selected pdf will be multiplied this many times.
- A button to generate a single output .pdf file.

When user clicks on the generate output button - a single output.pdf need to be generated and it should have the content of the original .pdf duplicated as many time as user specified in the text box.

Notes:

1. In the UI, user can select any valid .pdf file (content could be anything - text or image or combination or whatever really). Let's say the size of this .pdf file is 2 Mb.

Code I have:

```
GenerateContentDuplicatedPDF(string existingFileFullPath, string outputFileFullPath, int iNumberOfMerges)
{
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        using (PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(existingFileFullPath))
                        {
                            using (PdfDocument SourceDocument1 = new PdfDocument(pdfReader))
                            {
                                WriterProperties properties = new WriterProperties().SetCompressionLevel(CompressionConstants.NO_COMPRESSION);

                                using (PdfWriter pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(memoryStream, properties))
                                {
                                    using (PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(pdfWriter))
                                    {
                                        PdfMerger merge = new PdfMerger(pdfDocument);

                                        for (int i = 0; i < iNumberOfMerges; i++)
                                        {
                                            merge.Merge(SourceDocument1, 1, SourceDocument1.GetNumberOfPages());
                                        }

                                        merge.Close();
                                        SourceDocument1.Close();

                                        byte[] result = memoryStream.ToArray();

                                        File.WriteAllBytes(outputFileFullPath, result);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
}
```

It works and the output is as expected. The generated .pdf has content duplicated as expected.

What is the issue:

I was expecting the output file that gets generated would have the size multiplied by the number of times user wants the content duplicated.

For example: If user has selected a 2 Mb file, and entered 10 as the number, then I expect the output to be 20Mb. But iText7 is generating a file around 2.7 Mb. This is happening for all types of content, be it text or image or combination.

I have set the compression level to No compression too but still its the same. I want the generated output file to multiple the file size as well.

Not sure what is going wrong here or if iText7 is cleverly optimized to minimize the pdf size with duplicate content when the file is generated. Can I override this behavior?

Comment: for my particular requirement, I want the file size to be multiplied too.

Comment: Content could be text or image, we need to retain it as is during cloning.

Comment: You open the source file once and merge from the identical `PdfDocument` instance each time.  Have you tried opening new `PdfDocument` instances in the loop and so merging from different `PdfDocument`s?